# getc() crashes when trying to read after the last \n in a file

Tags: c, eof, fgetc

I have a an issue where `fgetc()` would crash upon trying to read beyond the last character in a stream (there is no file being opened, I am redirecting a text file to `stdin`). In the following code, with a file that contains a single character and a newline, it does not get to the "something" at the end - it does not even return `EOF`, merely quits.

I am somewhat at my wits' end here, really not sure what I am doing wrong. It's probably me not knowing something critical, but I have no idea what it is.

I did try to check with `feof()`, but it did not even get to it.

```
int p;
while ( (p = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF ) {
    printf("%c", p);
}
printf("something.\n");
```

I tried changing the previous `char p` to `int p`, to no avail.

Comment: `int p;` instead of `char p;`

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` and not `char`.

Comment: Is that really it? Gonna check real quick, feeling mighty dumb right now.

Comment: Nope, still not getting to the last line.

Comment: The exact code in the (edited) question works fine when copypasted inside `int main() { … }` and the input is piped from `echo x`.

Comment: Strange, I am getting crashes there when using the feature of eclipse that replaces console input with a text file.

Comment: Try directly from the command-line.

Comment: Okay, it works. Seems the issue is with the eclipse side. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Eclipse sucks.</flame> =)